# write to a file array of integer c#

Tags: c#

I want to write to a file 2 arrays of integers that are being swapped.
I know that I may not write the code very well but how can I make to work?
My code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HomeworkClean
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        RandomFunction();
        PrintListArray();
        CheckingSwappingNumbers();
        PrintListArray();
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
    public static long[] arrayOfIntNumbers = new long[10];
    public static void RandomFunction()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfIntNumbers.Length; i++)
        {
            arrayOfIntNumbers[i] = rnd.Next(100);
        }
    }
    public static void PrintListArray()
    {


        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfIntNumbers.Length; i++)
        {
            new Print(arrayOfIntNumbers[i].ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

    }

    private static void Swapping(ref long firstNumber, ref long secondNumber)
    {
        long auxVariable = firstNumber;
        firstNumber = secondNumber;
        secondNumber = auxVariable;
    }
    public static void CheckingSwappingNumbers()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfIntNumbers.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i; j < arrayOfIntNumbers.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                if (arrayOfIntNumbers[i] > arrayOfIntNumbers[j])
                {
                    Swapping(ref arrayOfIntNumbers[i], ref arrayOfIntNumbers[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }


}

public class Print
{
    public Print(string number)
    {
        //Console.Write(number + " ");
        PrintToFile(number);
    }

    public void PrintToFile(string a)
    {
        string n = a;

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\\Users\\(myName)\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\HomeworkClean\\HomeworkClean\bin\\Debug", n);

    }
}
}
```

In the PrintListArray I have intended to create a new Print which gives as a parameter the string representation of the array and from Print to access the method PrintToFile. But what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what exactly is the error?

Comment: You are missing the file name in your path.

Comment: The program stops and it says that there are some illegal characters in path.But I don't know whats's wrong.The address is corect, I went into the folder bin project, I create a new file and then I added the path here.

Comment: normally you should use @ in front of the string instead of using \\ within.  the filepath problem could be the blanks in your folder names. pls try it with a folder that has no blanks inside. In addition to you having put no filename only the folder name there

Comment: Additionally to what Tjaart is highlighting (= "Debug" is not a file name), you shouldn't be using `WriteAllText` in this way. It goes against the purpose of your code (you are rewriting the whole file every time and thus only one number will be kept).

Comment: @varocarbas: Disposing *what* object?  `WriteAllText()` is a `static` method.  How would you use a `using` block for that?

Comment: @David Honestly, I rarely (= never) use `WriteAllText` (to avoid memory problems) and my comment was a mere generic reference assuming an equivalent behaviour to the one of stream (variables); I didn't analyse the exact situation properly, my bad. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

You have saved `array.Length` items in your array.
if you want to write this Arrays into a File you need a `Stream`. A `StreamWriter` is a good option, but there is also a easier way:

```
public static void WriteToFile()
{
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var arrayElement in arrayOfIntNumbers)
    {
        stringBuilder.AppendLine(arrayElement.ToString());
    }

    File.AppendAllText(@"yourPathOfTheFile\array.txt", stringBuilder.ToString());
}
```

First use a `StringBuilder` to build the `string` you want to write to the `File`. And then write the lines with:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"yourPathOfTheFile\array.txt", stringBuilder.ToString());
```

So each number of the array is in a seperate line which makes it also very easy to read.

Answer (score 2):

There is *a lot* wrong with this code...

First off, you shouldn't be performing this file I/O *in a constructor*.  A constructor should just *build* an instance of an object, nothing else.  Use methods to perform logic.

Second, you're not specifying an actual *file* when you try to write to a file:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\\Users\\(myName)\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\HomeworkClean\\HomeworkClean\bin\\Debug", n);
```

That's a *folder*.  You can't write to a *folder*, you have to write to a *file*.  Something as simple as this would work better:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("output.txt", n);
```

(That file path may also be having issues with the symbol `(myname)`, not sure if that was intentional or not but it doesn't look like the folder name you want.)

Third, you're *overwriting* the file every time.  `WriteAllText()` will completely overwrite the contents of the file.  So after the program is done all you're going to have is the *last* value, instead of all of the values.  The quickest fix for that is to simply use `AppendAllText()` instead:

```
System.IO.File.AppendAllText("output.txt", n);
```

---

Note that there are *more efficient* ways to write an array to a file.  But as an exercise in simply getting your current code to work, the above should help.  As far as efficiency goes, consider that you are *opening a file, writing to it, and closing it again* with *every* iteration of your loop.  Instead, **as another exercise** see if you can find a way to loop over your values and turn them into one big string, and then write that to a file *only once*.

Comment: And why not writing each line right after the given value is being generated, rather than wasting an additional variable (an array or a string)? You can open a stream before the loop starts and close it after it ends. Additionally to save memory by avoiding intermediate storage, this approach allows to create as big files as required (not the case with the WriteAll versions).

Comment: @varocarbas: Indeed, there are *many* ways in which the OP's code can be improved.  The entire application could probably be clearly and succinctly written in only a few lines of code.  Given that the asker is clearly a beginner, I would recommend he/she take an incremental approach to refactoring and improving the code.

Comment: I see that. Your answer is good (I +1ed it). I am just highlighting the kind of things which newbies usually run away from. The write/readall approaches (and/or writing less lines of code) tend to be very attractive to them; that's why my comment.